# How to stop and shutdown an entire hazelcast cluster?

Tags: java, hazelcast

How do you stop and shutdown a hazelcast cluster? My observation from testing is that whenever a node ist stopped by HazelcastInstance#shutdown() the cluster tries to re-balance or backup the data. How can I first "stop" the cluster and then shut it down? (Or is my observation wrong?)

Comment: any news? any answers?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [isClusterSafe](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/core/PartitionService.java#L139) as in below example :

```
public class ShutdownCluster {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HazelcastInstance member1 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    HazelcastInstance member2 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    HazelcastInstance member3 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

    if(member1.getPartitionService().isClusterSafe()) {
        IExecutorService executorService = member1.getExecutorService(ShutdownCluster.class.getName());
        executorService.executeOnAllMembers(new ShutdownMember());
    }
}

private static class ShutdownMember implements Runnable, HazelcastInstanceAware, Serializable {

    private HazelcastInstance node;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        node.getLifecycleService().shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void setHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstance node) {
        this.node = node;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's never too late for an answer :)

If you want to not have migration events fired during shutdown, you can change cluster state to PASSIVE:

```
hazelcastInstance.getCluster().changeClusterState(PASSIVE);
```

I recommend doing this inside such if:

```
if (partitionService.isClusterSafe()) {
    hazelcastInstance.getCluster().changeClusterState(PASSIVE);
    hazelcastInstance.getCluster().shutdown(); 
    // or send exit command to each node, as in mrck answer - remember that then action must be an AllowedDuringPassiveState
}
```

In Passive and Frozen state, Hazelcast won't do migration and - because of that - you won't have errors when shutting down cluster. If block is helpful to be sure, that changing state and shutdown is safe to do to prevent data loss

Answer (score 0):

When testing I often use a Hazelcast.shutdownAll()

This will kill all the instances.

Comment: From the javadoc: "Shuts down all running Hazelcast Instances on this JVM. It doesn't shutdown all members of the cluster but just the ones running on this JVM." So it explicitly doesn't do what I need.

Comment: Ah ok, so you have different JVM's. I thought that all members were part of the same JVM.

One thing you can do is submit a runnable to a distributed executor and execute it on all members. This runnable can do a System.exit.

Is this purely for testing purposes or do you want to terminate members in production?

Comment: (sorry for the extremely late reply) I want to gracefully shutdown the whole cluster in production.

Comment: I tried same but not able to do..also Iam using 3.5 verison where as log says . INFO: [192.168.1.3]:5702 [dev] [3.9.2] Trying to join to discovered node

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
HazelcastInstance.getLifecycleService().shutdown();
```